# Rails radio_button_tag allows multiple input to be selected . why?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms, radio-button

I am creating a form. It has a radio_button_tag. Also I am setting the 'id' for that radio_button_tag dynamically. The problem is the radio_button_tag allows multiple input to be selected and I cannot deselect after selecting a radio_button.

```
   <% options.each do |option| %>
     <li><%= radio_button "#{option.name}", "#{option.id}", false,  class: 'radio-checkbox' %>
         <%= label_tag( "#{option.name}") %></li>

   <% end %>
```

What happens in the form is if there are 2 options, 'yes' and 'No' , It allows me to check both 'Yes' and 'No' at the same time.

Why it is happening?

Also I cannot deselect an option after selecting it once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to combine different radio buttons into one group you need to give them same name, looks like you are giving different.

```
<% options.each do |option| %>
  <li><%= radio_button_tag :some_same_name, "#{option.id}", false,  class: 'radio-checkbox' %>
  <%= label_tag( "#{option.name}") %></li>

<% end %>
```

Comment: It works fine. I understood what is the problem also.